# What is the opposite of an Exception when considering execution flow?

Tags: python, exception, terminology

I've tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) because that's what I'm using and there may be specific terminology around it, but I wouldn't be surprised if this question holds for other languages too.

Consider the following:

```py
try:
  raise Exception()
except Exception as e:
  print('oh no')

print('done')
```

Here, we'd say that "*an exception was raised*", or that at the `print('oh no')` we are "*handling an exception*".

What terminology do we use to discuss the following flow? (when no exception occurs)

```py
try:
  pass
except Exception as e:
  print('oh no')

print('done')
```

- Is there an antonym for "*exception*" in this context?
- Can this really be referred to as "*successful*", with the previous block *not* referred to as "*successful*"?
- Is the best we have "*without exception*"?

Both paths can be used for an ultimately successful block of code, and functions higher in the stack may be unaware of the exceptions that are occurring, so I'm interested primarily in this locality... when a specific block that *could* raise (and possibly handle) an exception doesn't...

Comment: Don't forget that a block of code may raise exceptions inside it but they get handled successfully (either by itself or further up the stack) which means it can continue and succeed in its task even if got trickier than expected along the way...

Comment: I think you're confirming my "_Couldn't both flows be part of an ultimately successful flow?_" question... which is good. I'll add words to limit the scope to "_local_" code.

Comment: I think this question argues semantics. Before searching the thesaurus for antonyms, I would propose *expected* is an antonym to *exception*: thesaurus.com suggests, among others (mine is not listed), "normality." In keeping with arguing semantics, I would say that one may *successfully handle* an exception. However, by definition, an exception is something unintended and should be considered "unsuccessful."

Comment: @AndrewFalanga: semantically it could be 'inception', then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is there an antonym for "exception" in this context?

Not really. We assume the 'default' is that it all worked well. Exceptions are, after all, exceptional.

- Can this really be referred to as "successful", with the previous block not referred to as "successful"?
- Couldn't both flows be part of an ultimately successful flow?

Both of these hinge on the fact that different usages of exceptions have different purposes - and thus different meanings of "success", even within the same program. For example: We want to read a file or create it if it doesn't exist. So you try to open a file that doesn't exist, which raises an exception. It was "unsuccessful" in opening that file, but that just means we need to create it. Since that is something we intend to do or intend to have happen, the program can still exit successfully.

- Is the best we have "without exception"?

That sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
  pass
except Exception as e:
  print('oh no')
else:
  print("No worries! nothing was excepted!!! :)")
finally:
  print("This will always print!! regardless of exception!... even if you return from inside the try/except/or else")
```